# Can a computer output video and charge on the same USB-C Thunderbolt port?

Tags: thunderbolt, usb-c

I currently own a 2017 Razer Blade Stealth 13, and recently I came across a monitor that only takes Thunderbolt as an input. Luckily for me, my laptop has a Thunderbolt plug, however that plug also happens to be its charging port.

Does there exist a splitter that would allow me to output video and charge through the same port? If not, why? From what I've been seeing it doesn't seem like you can, but I don't understand why when there exist splitters split the power to another USB-C port and an HDMI port.

Comment: So what is your question? Thunderbolt allows you to do exactly what you describe. So that is that for that answer. Are you asking about a hub to create additional ports? Those exist. Do a search for “USB C Dock” and there are tons of options available. Something like [this one from Other World Computing](https://www.owcdigital.com/products/usb-c-dock) should work. Look for the words “Pass-through USB-C data / charging port.” and check what max amount of watts it can handle for pass-through. It should be equal or higher for your laptop. Seems like it needs 65W to charge.

Comment: @JakeGould This item only has one output USB-C thunderbolt port. This would not allow me to achieve what I'm aiming for.

Comment: @JakeGould I would need something like this (https://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-F4U090/) expect would allow charging.

Comment: Do you understand that for charging you simply need USB-C passthrough? USB-C and Thunderbolt don’t care about the data specs for power. The Belkin device —and on checking again the Other World Computing dock I linked to — are purely USB-C so they could not drive the monitor. You need something like this then: Another model of [dock from Other World Computing](https://www.owcdigital.com/products/thunderbolt-3-dock-14-port).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Thunderbolt](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_(interface)) port interface can support daisy-chaining of up to 6 iterations, from the design and hardware capabilities standpoint.

That said — realistically speaking  — it may be difficult to sustain with any practicality without the proper equipment and knowledge to balance the actual power consumption between each peripheral.

I've had to resort to similar usages in the past — except with USB OTG (On-The-Go) peripherals — once when I had dropped my tablet and damaged the touch digitizer just as I was heading into an important meeting; even with an auxiliary power supply, the daisy chain setup still burned through my battery at an alarmingly unsustainable rate.